# How to store file data as class objects?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Imagine we have a class:

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self, model, name, price):
        self.model = model
        self.name = name
        self.price = price
```

And a .txt file:

```
201    BMW              1.2
202    Mercedes Benz    1.6
```

Is it possible to store '201' and '202' in `model`, 'BMW' and 'Mercedes Benz' in `name`, 1.2 and 1.6 in `price` without doing it manually...

```
    car1 = Car('201', 'BMW', 1.2)
    car2 = Car('202', 'Mercedes Benz', 1.6)
```

... as such, but rather by directly reading and storing data as class object?

I have tried parsing the data from file as such:

```
    cars = []
    file = open('store-data.txt')
    content = file.readlines()
    for x in range(len(content)):
        new_car = Car()
        cars.append(new_car)

    for car in cars:
        print(car)
```

But get the following error:

```
TypeError: __init__() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'model', 'name', and 'price'.
```

Comment: you need to write your own parsing code

Comment: Maybe check out pickling in python and let me know if that's what you mean

Comment: As I recall, you cannot pickle/serialize classes. What I have done in the past is to pickle/serialize the class initialization variables. The easiest way to do this is to write a method on your class which gives you a formatted string which you can store.

Comment: It is possible. Did you try to write code for the task? Did you run into a specific problem? If not - what do you imagine are the logical steps of the process, and which part do you need help with?

Comment: Read about YAML and pickle.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "directly reading and storing data as a class object"?  It sounds like your class needs something like a `load` and `store` method that can serialize and deserialize itself.

Comment: I've edited the question with how I tried to parse the data file. But don't know how to point to the objects in the class when calling it for it to work for each line. I have also looked up pickle but it is not the method I want to use.

Comment: The error message is stating that you have to pass extra information when using Product(): it expects the values for barcode, name and price, in a similar way as is needed for cars (model, name and price). So you have to get that information out of store-date.txt.

Comment: oops seems I forgot that I had changed the example. But yeah you get the general idea, it is essentially the same problem. This is exactly where my problem lies, I don't know how to parse the information from the text file and such that model, name and price are extracted from each line in the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is explained in the very same error message:
`TypeError: init() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'model', 'name', and 'price'`.

While you're trying to create your car without any value: `new_car = Car()`. The step you're missing is parsing the contents of each line in the file. In order to do that, you must partition the line by the space (the only delimiter in the sample you provided): `line.split()` will do what you need, and you will have three elements in the returned list: the model, the name of the maker, and the price. The next step is to convert the price to float (the other data seems to be text).

A call to `strip()` will also remove all possible prefix and postfix spaces.

```
parts = line.strip().split()
car = Car(part[0], part[1], float(part[2]))
```

The final code, following your own question:

```
    cars = []
    file = open('store-data.txt')
    content = file.readlines()
    for x in range(len(content)):
        parts = content[x].strip().split()
        new_car = Car(parts[0], parts[1], float(parts[2]))
        cars.append(new_car)
```

One important problem is that we are not closing the file, just opening it. The structure `with` will allow Python to close the file once the work on it is finished (when the `with` block is over).

Also you don't need to iterate over the number of lines in the file, you can run over them directly. This happens because `for` iterates over a list, and actually `range()` returns a list (of integers).

```
    cars = []
    with open('store-data.txt') as file:
        for x in file.readlines():
            parts = x.strip().split()
            new_car = Car(parts[0], parts[1], float(parts[2]))
            cars.append(new_car)
```

Now, there are a few issues suitable for polishing: converting a string to floating number (`float()`), can throw a **ValueError** exception. Also, we are counting that all lines will have the expected format.

```
    cars = []
    with open('store-data.txt') as file:
        for x in file.readlines():
            parts = x.strip().split()

            if len(parts) == 3:
                try:
                    new_car = Car(parts[0], parts[1], float(parts[2]))
                    cars.append(new_car)
                except ValueError:
                    print("Missing price in line: " + x)
            else:
                print("Formatting error in line: " + x)
```

Finally, since we have a maker "Mercedes Benz" which includes the delimiter inside its name, we have to take into account that maybe there is not going to be direct correspondence between the parts of the string and values for the car. We are sure that the first value is the model (#0, `parts[0]`), and the final one (#-1, `parts[-1]`, this is something special for Python) is the price. The values in-between are the different parts of the name of the maker.

Fortunately in Python we can extract a sublist from a bigger list (this is called slicing). Just enumerate the first position and the last one, and separate them with a colon. Remember that the final position is never included. So, the maker name will be included in the `parts[1:-1]`. We can also use the method `join(ch, l)` from **str**, which makes a new string using the members of the list `l`, separating them by the character `ch`. This will work even in the case when the maker name extends only for one part.

```
if len(parts) >= 3:
        model = parts[0]
        str_price = parts[-1]
        name = str.join(' ', parts[1:-1])
        
        try:
            new_car = Car(model, name, float(str_price))
```

So, finally:

```
    cars = []
    with open('store-data.txt') as file:
        for x in file.readlines():
            parts = x.strip().split()

            if len(parts) >= 3:
                model = parts[0]
                str_price = parts[-1]
                name = str.join(' ', parts[1:-1])
        
                try:
                    new_car = Car(model, name, float(str_price))
                    cars.append(new_car)
                except ValueError:
                    print("Missing price in line: " + x)
            else:
                print("Formatting error in line: " + x)
```

Comment: @Tomerikoo, that is fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this -

```
cars = []
file = open('store-data.txt')
content = file.readlines()
for c in content:
    model, name, price = c.strip().split()
    new_car = Car(model, name, price)
    cars.append(new_car)


for car in cars:
    print(car)
```

Comment: You're gonna have a problem with `Mercedes Benz`